# failed to open stream: Connection timed out

Tags: php, file

PHP File() connection timeout. Ive tried curl(), file_get_content(), fopen(). It seems like to fail. And this error happened after network issues. May someone please assist me? The variable $xml_template receives an empty string and I cannot continue to pass the XML while it is empty. but the variable $file is an URL and does well in having data.

```
$parm = base64_decode($this->parameters);
$file = OCTODOCGEN_URL.$this->xml.".php?".$parm;
$xml_template = join("",file($file));
```

Comment: "And this error happened after network issues" - then you need to fix these issues. There's nothing PHP, or other developers, can do about that

Comment: what do you think could have happened for file_get and file() to  stop working ? @nico

Comment: "Stop working" is something you should debug. Doesn't the error message contain more details about that?